# Twitter - Direct Message (API)

Tags: node.js, twitter, npm, node-modules

I'm trying to make a DM auto reply, something like a Q&A with the twitter API, but maybe I'm screwing something and I can't make it works.

Here my code:

```
stream.on('direct_message', function (eventMsg) {
    var msg = eventMsg.direct_message.text;
    var screenName = eventMsg.direct_message.sender.screen_name;
    var msgID = eventMsg.direct_message.id_str;

    if (screenName === ‘MyBotExample) {
        return callbackHandler(msgID);
    }

    else if (msg.search['Hi','Hello'] !== -1 ) {
        return T.post('direct_messages/new', { 
            screen_name: screenName,
            text: 'Hey, what can I do for you?'} , function () {
            callbackHandler(msgID);
        });
    }

    else if (msg.search[‘Apple’,’Red'] !== -1 ) {
        return T.post('direct_messages/new', { 
            screen_name: screenName,
            text: ‘Love it!’} , function () {
            callbackHandler(msgID);
        });
    }

    else {
        return T.post('direct_messages/new', {
            screen_name: screenName,
            text: "I don't know "
        }, function() {
            callbackHandler(msgID);
        });
    }
});
```

Instead of answering based on the conditions, all the answers responds as the first 'IF' was correct, even if is not true.

No matter what I ask, always replies with 
"Hey, what can I do for you?"

Maybe I can't use else if twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a JS expert, but I think you need;

```
msg.search('Hi','Hello') !== -1
```

instead of

```
msg.search['Hi','Hello'] !== -1
```

i.e use parentheses () instead of square brackets []. This would apply to each of the msg.search calls, in each condition.